# Simplify IActionResult return value logic

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

It would be nice to simplify the verbosity of this:

```
public IActionResult Get(int id)
{
    var movie = context.GetMovie(id);

    if (movie != null)
    {
        return Ok(movie);
    }
    else
    {
        return NotFound();
    }
}
```

with something like this:

```
public IActionResult Get(int id)
{
    var movie = context.GetMovie(id);
    return (movie != null) ? Ok(movie) : NotFound();
}
```

Of course, this is an error because the two objects in the ternary must be of the same type, not just sharing the same inheritance (or is this incorrect?).

The closest I can get is to explicitly cast one of the values as an `IActionResult`:

```
return (movie != null) ? Ok(movie) : (IActionResult) NotFound();
```

Is there a better option?

Comment: This should be applicable to both ASP.NET and ASP.NET Core - right?

Comment: Looks very readable the way it is to begin with. The `if` block returns so you could get rid of the `else`.

Comment: The two methods both return objects that inherit from [StatusCodeResult](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.statuscoderesult). If you use an intermediate variable like `StatusCodeResult result = (movie == null) ? NotFound() : Ok();` does it work?

Comment: As an aside, I agree with James that the code you have is perfectly fine the way it is. It's clear and readable as is. Shorter isn't necessarily better.

Answer (score 2):

So, as mentioned in comments: the code is readable and there are no issues with "verbosity". And as mentioned you can get rid of `else` statement, also it's a good habit to exclude "bad" cases at first.

```
public IActionResult Get(int id)
{
    var movie = context.GetMovie(id);

    if (movie == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    return Ok(movie);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If Ok returns null if you pass a null as argument you can simplify it like this

```
public IActionResult Get(int id, Context context) => Ok(context.GetMovie(id)) ?? NotFound();
```

Comment: Oh, now that's interesting!